# My coremlmodel gives different output on swift

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I create my MLMultiArray like this

```
var mlInput = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [1,2,12,120], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
```

and fill this with values which I get from json file like below

```
mlInput![0 * 12 * 120 + 0 * 120 + 5] = value as! NSNumber
```

basically I take index 0 over 2 index 0 over 12 and index 5 over 120

and giving it to model like below

```
let obj = try! mlModel.prediction(input: ml3dmodelInput(input: mlInput))
```

and get the result with these steps you see. It gives wrong prediction output. I did same things in python to test coremlmodel it did work well with python. I just did same steps fill the array with values from json giving it to model and get the output. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using cpu only.

```
let options = MLPredictionOptions()
options.usesCPUOnly = true
let obj = try! mlModel.prediction(input: ml3dmodelInput(input: mlInput), options: options)
```

Changed third step like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the array's `strides` to calculate the indices.

If the array has shape `[A, B, C, D]` then the correct index is:

```
a * strides[0] + b * strides[1] + c * strides[2] + d * strides[3]
```

However, you can also simply do:

```
mlInput[[a, b, c, d] as [NSNumber]] = value
```

Comment: I see that's guarantee method but nothing wrong about indexes. Also I tried second one from your suggested index method and it didn't work as well.